# Prepared statement to make pictures show up on php page, when JOINING tables

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, pdo

I currently have a loginsystem where a user is able to register and login as a user.
My system is based on PHP PDO.

When the user is logged in they should be able to upload a picture which is linked to their account.

Right now i have a fully functional loginsystem so thats great, and the user is currently able to upload a picture to the database, but he cant yet see it on the site.

Right now my problem is to make the pictures show up on the site.

I want the user to be able to see his OWN pictures that he uploaded, and not anybody elses pictures.

This is what i have so far! :)

This my Database!

> TABLE PICTURES with the following rows:
>
> descPicture
>
> id
>
> imageFullNamePicture
>
> titlePicture
>
> userid
>
> TABLE USERS with the following rows:
>
> user_email
>
> user_id
>
> user_name
>
> user_password
>
> user_phone
>
> user_zip

This is my CODE so far:

DBH.INC.PHP

```
    <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "chhoe17";


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",
    $username,
    $password,
    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));


}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

UPLOAD.INC.PHP

```
        <?php
    include "../upload.php";
      //Find the ID of the USER
     // session_start();
      include_once 'dbh.inc.php';


      $pictureTitle = ($_POST["filetitle"]);
      $pictureText = ($_POST["filedesc"]);
    //Fnd ID from the user
      //$user = $_SESSION["u_id"];
      $user = $_SESSION['u_id'];

      $queryUserID = 'SELECT user_id from '.'users'. ' where user_name="'. $user.'";';

      $stmt = $conn -> prepare($queryUserID);

      $stmt -> execute();
      $result = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


      //FileDic
      $fileDirectory = "../uploads/";

      $fileHandled = $fileDirectory . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);


      //The "tmp_name" is the temporary location the file is stored in the browser, while it waits to get uploaded
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $fileHandled)) {

          //echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
          $picture = 'INSERT INTO pictures (titlePicture, descPicture, userid, imageFullNamePicture) 
          VALUES (:titlePicture, :descPicture, :userid, :imageFullNamePicture);';
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($picture);
          $stmt -> bindParam(":titlePicture", $pictureTitle);
          $stmt -> bindParam(":descPicture", $pictureText);
          $stmt -> bindParam(":userid", $user);
          //$stmt -> bindParam(":userid", $result['user_id']);
          $stmt -> bindParam(":imageFullNamePicture", $fileHandled);
          $stmt -> execute(); 
          header("Location: ../upload.php?`Success");
          ?>

      <?php } else {

            header("Location: ../upload.php?Error");
          //echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
      }
      header("Location: ../upload.php");


UPLOAD.PHP

    <body>
<section class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <h2>Manage your pictures</h2>
        <?php
            //display a message and images if logged in!
        if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
          echo "Upload your pictures";

          echo '<div class="picture-upload">
            <h2>Upload</h2>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <form action="includes/upload.inc.php" id="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="text" name="filetitle" placeholder="Image title">
              <input type="text" name="filedesc" placeholder="Image description">
              <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
              <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
          </div>';

            }

          if (isset($_SESSION['users'])) {
          echo ' <section class="picture-links">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <h2>Pictures</h2> ';

          $user_data = 'SELECT * FROM' . ' users ' . 'INNER JOIN pictures on users.user_id 
          = pictures.userid WHERE name="' . $_SESSION['u_id'] . '";';
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($user_data);
          $stmt->execute();

          while ($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
            <div class="pictures">
                <a target="file" href=  <?php  ?>>
                    <img class="pic" src=  <?php echo $data['imageFullNamePicture']; ?>></a>
                <div class="titlePicture"><?php echo $data['titlePicture']; ?> <br> </div>
                    <div class="descPicture" >Your description:</div>
                    <div class="text"><?php echo $data['titleDesc']; ?> <br> ?> </div>
            </div>
            <?php
          }


        };
        ?>


    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>

<?php
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

So yea the problem is that i cant get the pictures that connects to the currently logged in user to show up on the page upload.php

I hope that somebody can help me! :)

EDIT!!!:

So i currently have this piece of code. IT should make the user see the pictures that he uploaded to the database, but it is very buggy. And it only shows one picture per user. Can somebody help make this work.

```
        if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
          echo ' <section class="picture-links">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Pictures</h2> ';

          ?>

        <div id="pictures">
            <?php



            $sql = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE userid = '{$_SESSION['u_id']}'";

            //$sql = "SELECT * FROM pictures ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 20;";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $pictures = $stmt->fetchAll();

           // if ($pictures !== null) {
              foreach ($pictures as $pic)
                ?>
            <figure id="<?php echo $pic['id']; ?>">
            <b><figcaption><?php echo $pic["titlePicture"] ?>
            <img src = <?php echo $pic["imageFullNamePicture"]  ?>>
            <?php echo $pic["descPicture"] ?> <br>
            </figure>
            <?php

         // }
        }
        ?>

  </div>
```

Comment: Are the picture paths saving successfully to the database? Does it deliver the picture if you manually type in the path to the file? In your `WHERE` clause, you check for name equal to u_id. Should it be `WHERE users.user_id = :u_id` (then bind the u_id)? And i do beliebe @ArtisticPhoenix is right that you need ti FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: It might help to get on phpmyadmin (assuming that's what you have) and query for picture files for a user, to make sure you have that right. Then work that query back into your php.

Comment: Are the picture paths saving successfully to the database?  = yes yes yes

Comment: You called `session_start()` before using Upload.inc.php ?  None of the `$_SESSION` and hence none of your output will work if you didn't  `if (isset($_SESSION['users'])) {`

Comment: Thanks for you help, i editeted the code ! I changed the code so something better, but it stille dosent work

Answer (score 1):

Your fetching the data as numerically indexed arrays `PDO::FETCH_NUM`, yet your using the keys in your code:

UPLOAD.INC.PHP

```
 //instead of PDO::FETCH_NUM
 while ($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
  ...
    <?php echo $data['imageFullNamePicture']; ?>
  ...
  <?php }
```

Use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` instead.

Please don't do this with PDO:

```
 $user_data = 'SELECT * FROM' . ' users ' . 'INNER JOIN pictures on users.user_id 
      = pictures.userid WHERE name="' . $_SESSION['u_id'] . '";';
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($user_data);
 $stmt->execute();
```

If someone manages to get data in here `name="' . $_SESSION['u_id'] . '"` you've just defeated the whole purpose of preparing your SQL.  It shouldn't matter where that data came from, you never know when a simple coding mistake or something will allow user data into a session variable.

```
 $user_data = 'SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN pictures on users.user_id 
      = pictures.userid WHERE name=:u_id';
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($user_data);
 $stmt->execute(['u_id'=>$_SESSION['u_id']]);
```

It's that easy to prepare it properly.  You don't really need to even use `bind` whatever with PDO, unless you wan't to restrict the Type.  But I think it's also the only way to do `LIMIT :limit`.  Anyway I almost never use them.  In general both PHP and MySQL are smart enough to do the proper type casting.

PS.  don't forget to call `session_start()` if your using `$_SESSION` or none of that will work.  I didn't see it in the code that was posted, so I have to mention it.

Comment: Ahh i see that, that makes totally sense! Thank you! :)

I edited my post, and i changed the code to what you suggested :)

The pictures still dont show up tho, and i dont get any errors aswell :)

do you have an idea what i should do?

Comment: @Bobbalob check if the pictures path is valid, that means copy and paste the path from the database directly and try accesing it. It could be bad formatted or the directory does not have read permissions

Comment: Once I spent 5 hours figuring out why an image wouldn't work.  The extension was `.JPG` instead of `.jpg` that was 2009ish.  Never did that again.

Comment: I appreciate your HELp a lot! :) I edditet my post because i changed the code you help would be nice!